# svn:ignore - how does it work?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I have difficult in understanding the svn:ignore property. It would be nice if someone could help me on this.

I checked out a grails web app from a svn repository that has svn:ignore property applied for *.log files and /target folder. Obviously, when I checked out the *.log files and /target folder was missing. After working on this grails app on my local working copy, the /target directory and *.log files gets created. Now, when I commit the changes into the svn repo, will the /target files and *.log files get committed too? or will they be automatically ignored because of the svn:ignore property already existing on the svn copy of the grails app?

Hope I have made myself clear.

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: If you want people to carry on answer your questions, you need to approve the answers given to your earlier questions (see check mark on the left of answers).

Comment: Agreed. Please approve or "accept" answers given to your posts. Otherwise you aren't helping the community's rating system.

Comment: I am sorry I dint know that.. I approved answers for my previous questions and will continue to do so..

Comment: Cool. Welcome to the Stackoverflow community!  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The svn:ignore property contains a list of file patterns which certain
>   Subversion operations will ignore. Perhaps the most commonly used
>   special property, it works in conjunction with the global-ignores
>   run-time configuration option (see the section called “Config”) to
>   filter unversioned files and directories out of commands svn status,
>   svn add, and svn import.
>
> The rationale behind the svn:ignore property is easily explained.
>   Subversion does not assume that every file or subdirectory in a
>   working copy directory is intended for version control. Resources must
>   be explicitly placed under Subversion's management using the svn add
>   or svn import commands. As a result, there are often many resources in
>   a working copy that are not versioned.
>
> Now, the svn status command displays as part of its output every
>   unversioned file or subdirectory in a working copy that is not already
>   filtered out by the global-ignores option (or its built-in default
>   value). This is done so that users can see if perhaps they've
>   forgotten to add a resource to version control.
>
> But Subversion cannot possibly guess the names of every resource that
>   should be ignored. Also, quite often there are things that should be
>   ignored in every working copy of a particular repository. To force
>   every user of that repository to add patterns for those resources to
>   their run-time configuration areas would be not just a burden, but has
>   the potential to clash with the configuration needs of other working
>   copies that the user has checked out.
>
> The solution is to store ignore patterns that are unique to the
>   resources likely to appear in a given directory with the directory
>   itself. Common examples of unversioned resources that are basically
>   unique to a directory, yet likely to appear there, include output from
>   program compilations. Or—to use an example more appropriate to this
>   book—the HTML, PDF, or PostScript files generated as the result of a
>   conversion of some source DocBook XML files to a more legible output
>   format.

**Reference:**

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html

Answer (score 1):

The svn:ignore property contains a list of file patterns or directory names which certain Subversion operations will ignore. If you commit the changes into the svn repo, the /target files and *.log files will not be committed and they are automatically ignored because of the svn:ignore property that already exists on the svn copy of the grails app.